# Using if/ else statement to check multiple answers?

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans-8

### A few details:

- I am using Netbeans 8.0
- All code provided is from a button in a JFrame in my main package.

### What my program is suppose to do:

My program consists of a single Jframe that has:

- 6 TextFields where the user must input his answer
- 6 Lables to show user what the question is.
- 1 Button to process everything.
- 1 TextField for the final mark.

My Programming is a easy math game that helps users develop their multiplication tables.In the first frame there are only six multiplication tables (1 times 1 , 1 times 2 ect...)

So I want to develop if else statements to check ALL of the answers are correct and add them to my final score.

Here's my code for my button so far:

```
//Declaring my counter
    int TotalCorrect = 0;
   
    //Declaring my Correct answers
    //To compare to User answers
    
    int Answer1     =1;
    int Answer2     =2;
    int Answer3     =3;
    int Answer4     =4;
    int Answer5     =5;
    int Answer6     =6;
   
    
    // Converting TextField answers to int
    int ConvertedAnswer1 = Integer.parseInt(txfUserAnswer1.getText());
    int ConvertedAnswer2 = Integer.parseInt(txfUserAnswer2.getText());

    
    if (ConvertedAnswer1 == Answer1)
    {
    //Adding +1 for total correct
    TotalCorrect = + 1;
    
    }
    else
    {
    
    TotalCorrect = +0;    
      
    }
   
    //Converting int to string
   
    String FinMark = Integer.toString(TotalCorrect);
   
    // Printing Users Mark
    
    txfOutput.setText(FinMark);
```

The problem is when I use this code directly under the else:

```
if (ConvertedAnswer2 == Answer2)
    {
    //Adding +1 for total correct
    TotalCorrect = + 1;
    
    }
    else
    {
    
    TotalCorrect = +0;    
      
    }
```

The program crashes. Not the first or second answer gets marked.

Comment: Forgot to add! If anyone could suggest any other way to this that would be great , thanks.

Comment: Problem looks very small but very unclear to answer it.

Comment: Adding 1 to a variable is done by `TotalCorrect += 1;` not by `...= + 1;`

Comment: The program crashes? With what error?

Comment: you can also use `switch` instead of  `if else`

Comment: Edit your question and add the full error text. Also, please conform to Java coding conventions: Type names (class,interface,enum) should start with a capital letter (e.g. `BigPicture`). Method, variable and field names should start with a lowercase letter (e.g. `bigPicture`), and constants should be all-caps (e.g. `BIG_PICTURE`).

Comment: A program doesn't "crash" when a correct and harmless if statement is added.

Comment: what is the point of trying to increment by `0` and assign it to something?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all = + is not correct, you should use += to add the value to TotalCorrect, second adding 0 does nothing, so why do it at all?

So why not just do:

```
if (ConvertedAnswer1 == Answer1){ TotalCorrect += 1; }
if (ConvertedAnswer2 == Answer2){ TotalCorrect += 1; }
if (ConvertedAnswer3 == Answer3){ TotalCorrect += 1; }
if (ConvertedAnswer4 == Answer4){ TotalCorrect += 1; }
```

You could probably do it even prettier, but this will work.

Comment: Thanks I will try this ! Like I said I'm completely new to this language, I'm an high-school student who has only begun learning it. I really appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Also take al look at Pauls Answer below, his solution is better but a bit more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code will cause problems, since it's a simple assignment, not the increment you wanted:

- `TotalCorrect = + 1;` should be `TotalCorrect += 1;`

And adding 0 to `TotalCorrect` doesn't make any sense.

This can be solved way more efficient using loops and arrays:

```
int[] answers = new int[]{1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6};;
int[] input = new int[6];
int correct = 0;

for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
    input[i] = Integer.parseInt(txtfUserAnswer[i].getText());
    if(input[i] == answers[i])
        correct += 1;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sry, i've corrected it. didn't pay enough attention

Comment: Thanks, I have already fixed my problem. Will try this next time. But to be honest I don't know much of what is going on in this code :P